# Config server not able to find the remote application file

Tags: spring-boot, configserver

I'm having issue with referring the application/config file on a config server. 
I already have a GAIA DEV Pool ready.

This is what I have done so far -

- Created an `application.yml` file with required config property

  `hello-service:
     message: Hello World From Spring Cloud Config Server`
- Checked it in git repo - `feature/cs-hello` branch.
- Logged in to dev pool `cf login -a [dev-pool-url]`
- Created the config server : 
  `cf create-service -c  "{\"git\": { \"label\": \"feature/cs-hello\", \"uri\": \""[GIT HTTPS URL]\", \"username\": \"[USERNAME]\", \"password\": \"[PASSWORD]\" } }" p-config-server standard config-server`

Now, my referring [https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-4/common/config-server/configuring-with-git.html]  - since my config file is not on the master branch, I used `label`.

Somehow my code is not finding the application file on config server.

Anyone here who can point me a direction?

Answer (score 0):

Once you are done with config server creation, you need to bind that service with your application and you can need to provide following information in `bootstrap.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: appName
```

There  is a way to check either your config server is connecting to repository or not. Go to

> PCF manager -->Services--> Config Server--> Manage

and then you should be able to see

> Config server is online